# copy order between collections

Tags: java, sorting, collections

In my application I need to keep resulting collection in the same order as requested (user sends a list of what he wants and it is desirable to answer him in the same order).

Data, what I will send to user is generated by underlying layers, and they neither know the correct order, nor generate ordered result. So I have to order it myself.

My approach is following, but I think that it's not necessary to implement it, because there should be some standard way. So, what would you recommend?

```
public class KeepOrder {

/**
 * Knows how to extract A from B.
 * 
 * @param <A>
 * @param <B>
 */
public interface Extractor<A, B> {

    A extract(B from);

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static <T, F> Collection<T> keepOrder(final Collection<T> data, final Collection<F> order,
        final Extractor<F, T> extractor) {

    final Comparator<T> tComparator = new Comparator<T>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {

            final F field1 = extractor.extract(o1);
            final F field2 = extractor.extract(o2);

            for (final F currentField : order) {
                if (currentField.equals(field1) && currentField.equals(field2)) {
                    return 0;
                }

                if (currentField.equals(field1)) {
                    return -1;
                }

                if (currentField.equals(field2)) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
    };

    return new TreeSet<T>(tComparator) {
        {
            addAll(data);
        }
    };

}
```

}

Comment: Why not just override compareTo?

Comment: .compareTo() of what class do you mean? <T> doesn't have .compareTo()

Comment: This is actually pretty similar to a question I asked- [how do I reorder a collection according to a related list of ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802096/reordering-a-collection-according-to-a-related-list-of-ids). It's possible the answers there will help you - they certainly helped me!

Answer (score 5):

If the order is important in your collection, you should restrict yourself to `List`s.

From [the documentation of `List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

> **An ordered collection (also known as a sequence).** The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted. The user can access elements by their integer index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to add to my question, that data, what I will send to user is generated by underlying layers, and they neither know the correct order, nor generate ordered result. So I have to order it myself. Not sort but order.

Comment: Then do something like `new ArrayList<Type>(unorderedCollection)`.