# Reordering a collection according to a related list of ids

Tags: java, collections, sequence

I have a Collection (unordered) of objects with an *id* property, and an (ordered) List of *ids*. **The id list is not sorted**. I'd like to create a List of the objects in my Collection, ordered according to the List of ids.

I didn't see a method for this in Guava or Apache Commons - but that's exactly what I'm looking for. A library function with a good implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your id list has its own order; you're not just using the natural order, right?

Here's the Guava solution:

```
Ordering.explicit(idList)
     // constructs a "fluent Comparator" that compares elements in the
     // explicitly specified order
  .onResultOf(new Function<MyObject, Id>() {
    public Id apply(MyObject o) { return o.getId(); }
   }) // make this a Comparator<MyObject> that compares on IDs
  .sortedCopy(myObjects); // get the sorted copy of the collection
```

That's it.  Nothing to it.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Alternately, if you know IDs are unique, it might just say

```
Map<Id, MyObject> objectsById =
  Maps.uniqueIndex(myObjects, GET_ID_FUNCTION); // defined elsewhere
List<MyObject> sortedObjects = Lists.newArrayList();
for (Id id : sortedIds) 
  sortedObjects.add(objectsById.get(id));
```

Comment: This is interesting, and pretty much what I was expecting.

Comment: Alternately, if you want to sort the input list in-place, just use `Collections.sort(list, Ordering.explicit(idList).onResultOf(..))`, since an `Ordering` is also a `Comparator`.

Answer (score 1):

If your unordered input is no more specific than Collection and your List of ids is in an arbitrary order (not decreasing numerically or something like that), your simplest and quite performant approach is probably this. The cost is linear, O(m+n) where m is the number of ids in your initially sorted list and n is the number of values to sort.

```
Map<IDType, ValueType> keyed = new HashMap<IDType, ValueType>();
for (ValueType value : unsortedCollection) {
    keyed.put(value.getId(), value);
}

List<ValueType> sorted = new ArrayList<ValueType>();
for (IDType id : sortedIds) {
    ValueType value = keyed.get(id);
    if (value != null) {
        sorted.add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my first thought, if I didn't find something cleaner already written in a library. It'll probably either be this or what @Louis suggested.

Comment: It sounds like the Guava solution will do it, too. Unless performance is critical I would just pick whatever you find most readable.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a given order you want, that may or may not be numerically ascending / descending?

I would recommend making your own Predicate below.
`org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.find(java.util.Collection collection,`
                                    [Predicate](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Predicate.html) `predicate);`

and loop over your specific ordering finding each actual object in the unordered list.  N^2 solution

and a creative use of `java.util.collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)`, a org.apache.find(), and `java.util.collections.swap(List list, int i, int j)` you may get away from n^2

Answer (score 0):

Read the List of ID's, copying the Collection into a new List in the ID List order.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that implements Comparable. In that class, do the sorting according to your ordered list of ids. Then define a TreeSet based on the Comparable class. A greatly simplified example is shown below.

e.g.

```
public class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {
  private Integer id;

  // a map of IDs to how they are ordered.
  private static Map<Integer, Integer> idOrder = null;

  public MyObject(Integer id) {
      setId(id);

      if (idOrder == null) {
           idOrder = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
           idOrder.put(17, 1);
           idOrder.put(27, 2);
           idOrder.put(12, 3);
           idOrder.put(14, 4);
      }
  }

  public int getId() {
      return (this.id);
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public int compareTo(MyObject anotherThing) {
    return (idOrder.get(this.getId()).compareTo(idOrder.get(anotherThing.getId()))); 
  }
}
```

Then, define and populate your set like so:

```
private Set<MyObject> mySet = new TreeSet<MyObject>;
mySet.add(new MyObject(12));
mySet.add(new MyObject(17));
```

When you do a mySet.add(), it will automatically sort according to your MySort class. If you iterate over the resulting TreeSet, the "17" entry will come before the "12" entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- implement the interface [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in your object and then call [Collections.sort(List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)
- implement the interface [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) with a new class and then call [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

With the first solution you have to modify your object, with the second one you have to create another class but you can leave your object unmodified.
`<T>` is your object class.